# Using ldd for chroot

Tags: gcc, chroot, ldd

I've created very minimal chroot environment on sdb and mounted it on `/mnt/sdb`. I've also created a symbolic link `/mnt/sdb/bin/cc` that points to `/usr/bin/gcc`.

`ldd /mnt/sdb/bin/cc` returned

```
 linux-gate.so.1 => (0xb7829000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb76dd000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb782a000)
```

So I copied the necessary libraries by running:

```
 cp /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 /mnt/sdb/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
 cp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /mnt/sdb/lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Glancing through [this](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/) article, I figured that since `linux-gate.so.1` is a part of the kernel, I don't need to copy it over.

However, after I run `chroot /mnt/sdb /bin/sh` then try `cc` I get

```
cc: error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How come ldd couldn't tell cc needed libm.so.6? Is there an easy way to get cc to work in the chrooted environment without simply copying over all the libraries? I'd just like to use cc temporarily so that I can build tcc with it, then build everything else with tcc (I've also tried simply building tcc outside then using it in chroot, but I'm afraid that that might deserve its own post).

Note:

I'm using Debian in Virtualbox, and the only program that currently runs in the chroot environment is a single (static) busybox binary.